# Blocks in Episerver

Tags: episerver

So I am trying to create my first block. The idea of this block is to get latest news from an api end point and then show it on different pages on the website.

What I have understood is this

Create a block type, something like this

```
public class NewsBlock : BlockData
{

            [CultureSpecific]
            [Display(
                Name = "Heading",
                Description = "Add a heading.",
                GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
                Order = 1)]
            public virtual String Heading { get; set; }

}
```

Then I create a model for my Block

```
public class LatestNewsViewModel 
{
  public NewsBlock NewsBlock { get; private set; }
  public IEnumerable<dynamic> LatestNews { get; set; }

  public LatestNewsViewModel(NewsBlock latestNewsBlock, IEnumerable<dynamic> latestNews) 
  {
  NewsBlock = latestNewsBlock;
  LatestNews = latestNews;
}
}
```

Then I creata a block controller and in the index action I get data from my api and fill the block container data
Then I create a partial view and then from controller pass data into the view
Then from the dashboard I can add my block where ever I want on the site

Is this the way to do it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe note entirely relevant, but since you mentioned being new to Episerver I would just like to recommend that you start your ordering of properties on 10, and then increment by 10 or so onwards.

When you find yourself having a block or pagetype with multiple properties and then all of the sudden need to a few more in between, you won't necessarily have to correct the order value on all of them..

Comment: @Frostrar thanks a lot. Can I get some explanation about what that Order is? How it helps?

Comment: @ChaudhryMohsinAli it defines the order your properties are listed in All Properties editing (as opposed to On-page editing). You can read more about this in the documentation: http://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/Content/grouping-content-types-and-properties/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That seem about correct. Please note there are many ways and opinions on how to get your data from the content model through the controller to the actual view. The example below is just the most simple scenario I can come up with.

```
public class NewsBlock : BlockData
{    
            [CultureSpecific]
            [Display(
                Name = "Heading",
                Description = "Add a heading.",
                GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
                Order = 1)]
            public virtual String Heading { get; set; }

}
```

The controller

```
public class NewsBlockController : BlockController<NewsBlock>
{
    // GET: NewsBlock
    public override ActionResult Index(NewsBlock currentBlock)
    {
        // apistuff
        ApiModelWhatever returnFromApi = "whatever";

        var model = new LatestNewsViewModel(currentBlock, returnFromApi);
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class LatestNewsViewModel 
{
    public string Heading { get; private set; }
    public ApiModelWhatever ReturnFromApi { get; private set; }

    public LatestNewsViewModel(NewsBlock latestNewsBlock, ApiModelWhatever returnFromApi) 
    {
        Heading = latestNewsBlock.Heading;
        ReturnFromApi = returnFromApi;
    }
}
```

View

```
@model LatestNewsViewModel

<h2>@Html.PropertyFor(model => model.Heading)</h2>
```